# Is the sentence "how are the names of your dogs?" correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Searching in https://books.google.com, you can find that "how are the names" is infrequent than "what are the names", even than "which are the names".

However, the context in which I founded it, is when the phrase is followed by a verb. For example:

- How are the names arranged?
- How are the names listed?
- How are the names Williamsonia and Wielandiella to be used?

Is the sentence "how are the names of your dogs?" grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. You could say: What are the names of your dogs?

Comment: Or..how are your dogs! :)

Comment: "How are the names listed?", mentioned in the OP, is perfectly grammatical

Comment: But "How are the names listed" may not give you the names themselves.  The reply may be "in alphabetical order" or "by the dogs' ages" or "by the names of their breeds".  If you want to know the dogs' names, ask "What are the names of your dogs?" or "What are your dogs' names?"